# iCarousel iOS with reduced size views on the sides

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a circular carousel. I would like to always show 3 at a time. One view is centralized and the other two (the previous and the next) on a reduced size like the image below:

[image]

I am working with Xamarin.iOS but a solution in swift and object-c is welcomed.

This is the closest I could get:

[image]

I have this inside the iCarouselDelegate

> ```
> public override nfloat ValueForOption(iCarousel carousel, iCarouselOption option, nfloat value)
> {
>         switch (option)
>         {
>             case iCarouselOption.OffsetMultiplier:
>                 return 2f;
>
>             case iCarouselOption.Wrap:
>                 return 1.5f;
>
>             case iCarouselOption.VisibleItems:
>                 return count;
>
>             case iCarouselOption.Spacing:
>                 return 2f;
>
>             default:
>                 return value;
>         }
> }
> ```

and also:

> ViewCarousel.Type = iCarouselType.Rotary;

Comment: iCarousel as in the Nick Lockwood library written in Objective-C (https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)? That was last updated in 2017, and is badly out of date at this point. I would strongly advise against using it for new development.

Comment: You should be able to implement the U you show using collection view controllers. Those are quite flexible. Look up `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in Apple's docs.

Comment: Probably an improvement, but I am a bit too invested at this point to change implementations

Comment: I worked with iCarousel back in 2015 or so, and seem to remember that it had an option for linear lists as you show. It looks like you're set up for a circular carousel. You might want to run the demo app and look through the options (If it will still build and run.)

Comment: Yes, linear is close to what I need with wrap options, but I can't make the left and the right views smaller. Don't know if it is possible though

Comment: As I recall, there are settings you can adjust that alter the way items scale. You should be able to customize a linear carousel so that it looks like what you show.

Comment: I tried to build the iOS demos from the iCarousel package, and I'm getting a linker error that it can't find the file libarclite_iphonesimulator.a. That sounds like a pre-built file of some sort. Did you encounter that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue with the following line of code:

```
    public override CATransform3D ItemTransformForOffset(iCarousel carousel, nfloat offset, CATransform3D transform)
    {
        // How much smaller the left and right views should be relative to the center view (expressed as pixels)
        float viewSizeDifference = -100;

        // The horizontal spacing between the views (expressed as a multiple of the views width)
        float viewDistance = 1.17f;

        float transformZ = (float)(Math.Min(1.0f, Math.Abs(offset)) * viewSizeDifference);

        return transform.Translate(offset * carousel.ItemWidth * viewDistance, 0f, transformZ);
    }
```

but for this to work you also have to change the type to custom:

```
ViewCarousel.Type = iCarouselType.Custom;
```

Comment: I'm glad you solve your problem, and thanks for sharing your solution with the community. (Voted)

Comment: Be sure to accept your self-answer when the system allows you to.

Comment: Thanks @DuncanC, you led me to the right places. I will check out UICollection when I can